# 26 modulo in hill cipher encryption

Tags: matrix, encryption

I am reading about [Hill Cipher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hill_cipher) encryption algorithm, from the wikipedia. I see that I have a key as a matrix that must multiply by the the matrix of values. But there are 2 things I don't understand.

I don't know the mean of (mod 26). I know it is modulo 26, but I don't know for what it is applied?

As for the second issue, I can't understand where the matrix [15 14 7] is coming from?

Any good explanation will be highly appreciated .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`26` is the length of your dictionary, which happens to be the length of the English alphabet (A to Z). Using the modulo operator allows you to map every possible output of the matrix multiplication (encryption) to a letter in the alphabet (`834 = 2 (mod 26)` which is **C**), which lets you store the encrypted message in the form of a string of letters.

The `[15 4 7]` came from the matrix `[67 222 319] (mod 26)`:

[image]

The triple equals sign means that the matrix `[67 222 319]` is congruent to `[15 4 7]` modulo 26. Every element in the left-hand matrix should be congruent modulo 26 to the corresponding element in the right-hand matrix as well, so you apply the modulo operator to every element in the left-hand matrix to get every element in the right-hand matrix.

Comment: How is it possible to calculate it pro grammatically , fir example in java does '%' is used ?

Comment: Yep, that's the modulo operator. If you don't want to use a matrix algebra library you'll need to manually multiply the encryption matrix and the message vector together.

Comment: yes, I already did, but what do you mean in 'matrix algebra library' ?

Comment: The size of the encryption matrix is `n x n`, where `n` is the length of the string. If you have the message `Imalongmessage`, your matrix becomes a `14 x 14` matrix and it is somewhat complicated to multiply. It's totally doable from scratch, but I suggest you either find a matrix algebra library or make a basic `Matrix` class that can be multiplied together with another `Matrix` class. It isn't that hard to do.

Comment: How the Alphabets are represented ? I mean are they represented with starting from A - 1, B - 2, C - 3 and so on or A - 0, B - 1, C - 2 and so on?

Comment: Nice and detailed explanation @Blender. A small correction. Assuming we are using English alphabet to map the the result of mod 26. 834 mod 26 = 2, should be the letter C, as we would be having zero based numbering. Which is all the results from modulo 26 operation:
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25

Answer (score 0):

So, you multiply both matrices together, and then you get the encrypted matrix. You then **modulo every value of the resulting matrix by 26**.

The mod 26 just generally means, "this value is modulo 26."

Answer (score 0):

hi this is the so called modular arithmetic it's becoz there are 26 letters in the alphabet 0 is A 1 is B ... 25 is Z so what letter is 27 unclear that's why u wrap around the numbers with the modulo operator % or mod every time u get a number bigger than 25 or less then 0 u wrap around with mod 26 in that respect 27 is B becoz 27 mod 26 = 1 the matrix [15 14 7] came from [67 222 319] becoz 67 mod 26 = 15 222 mod 26 = 14 and 319 mod 26 = 7 :)