# Hill Cipher using a 2 x 2 Key Matrix

Tags: matrix, cryptography

I'm new to cryptography and I cannot seem to get my head around this problem:
The problem says that the Hill Cipher using the below 2 x 2 key matrix (K) was used to produce the ciphered text "KCFL".

```
K = (3   5)
    (2   3)
```

It then asks to use the Hill Cipher to show the calculations and the plain text when I decipher the same encrypted message "KCFL".

I know with other matrices, e.g. for the determinant there is usually a formula, such as:

```
a x d - b x c
```

However, for the Hill Cipher I am completely lost.

I have done the following:

a) found the inverse of K:

```
 K inverse =    (-3  5)
                (2  -3)
```

b) Found "KFCL":

```
KFCL = (10  5)
       (2  11)
```

c) The next step (mod 26) confuses me. How do I decipher (using mod 26) and the Cipher Key to find the plain text?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Many thanks.

Comment: A detailed explanation on how to encrypt and decrypt using Hill Cipher. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hill_cipher

Comment: After reading that little wiki, this is what I think you have to do. You need to find the inverse of the K matrix. Once you found the inverse take mod 26 of it. Then you multiple it with KCFL which is 2x2 matrix [(10,5),(2,11)] where (10,5) is row1 and (2,11) is row2.

Comment: @anonymous : Thank you for your input. I have edited the post (above) to show my workings. I am still unsure how part c) works. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To perform MOD26 of the matrix, take each number and MOD26. If the number is negative, add multiples of 26 until you hit a positive number.

This may also help you.

[26 modulo in hill cipher encryption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10646771/26-modulo-in-hill-cipher-encryption)

Comment: Thanks. What really confuses me about modulo is: why is: -30 Mod 26 = 22; whereas -23 Mod 26 = 3? ... I don't see the connection.

Comment: You need to add multiples of 26 until it's a positive number. So -30+26+26 = 22. Similarly, -23+26 = 3.

Comment: That explained it perfectly. I now get it. Thanks.

Comment: You're welcomed. For bigger negative numbers, you can perform division and round it up to get the multiple. Eg. -1234 mod 26 = (roundup(1234/26) * 26) - 1234 = 14.